# Shipping cost calculation for PayPal's “Buy Now” button

Tags: paypal

I need to generate a PayPal "Buy Now" button to sell a book.

Can someone explain to me how to implement the automatic shipping costs calculation with PayPal?

The documentation refers to an option that does not exist in the merchant menu. I've looked everywhere, can't seem to find it.

In case this is relevant, my account is based in Belgium.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is the same for accounts no matter the country, but I could be wrong. (I'm in Canada.)

Shipping preferences are under *Profile* (click the menu item, not the drop down) > *Shipping Calculations* (under Selling Preferences). You can try this link, but I don't know if it will work: https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-shipping

Here you can setup a flat rate or percentage and then enter in the amounts and price ranges they are for.

By the way, I too find PayPal's menu to be extremely confusing.

Comment: thank you. I don't have that menu item, which is already weird, but i can use the page.
Unfortunately, it's not exactly what i was looking for: i was hoping to have a price shown for a given destination. So if i'm from Ghana, i see on the checkout page:
item price + delivery to Ghana = total

Comment: I don't think this is possible with PayPal's basic shopping cart. You'll either need to setup (and I think pay for) their more advanced shopping cart or setup another shopping cart on/for your site. Also, you may want to update your question to reflect what you are truely looking for.